# Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, dictionary vs list in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, attr

I am trying to initialize a dictionary as a attribute in my object and trying to use defaultdict. Somehow, it works on Mac not Windows. What I want is:

```
1 {'1':[], '2':[]}
2 {'1':[], '2':[]}
```

Here is what I ve done so far.

```
class A:
    
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        self.x = self.y

    @property
    def y(self):
        ref = defaultdict(list)
        ls = ['1', '2']
        for i in ls:
            ref[i] = []
        return ref

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id}, {self.x}'.format(self=self)

def main():
    for i in range(2):
        me = A(i)
        print(me)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error message I'm having is:

```
KeyError: "'23'"
```

or some other numbers and varies every time.
The `self.y` function works when I am just directly accessing it. Like:

```
    for i in range(2):
        me = A(i)
        print(me.y)
```

Of course, before that I set:

```
class A: 
    
        def __init__(self, id):
            self.id = id    
            self.x =  []
```

then

```
    for i in range(2):     
        me = A(i)
        print(me)
```

I get

```
1 []
2 []
```

but I want

```
1 {'1':[]}
2 {'2':[]}
```

so I can add some values in dictionary values.

What am I doing wrong? It seems there is a problem in return values
when I sign `{}` instead of `[]`. Is there a way to figure out or work around it?

Comment: Why use a `defaultdict(list)` _and_ create two empty lists in it? Also it seems like you want each of your two instances of `A` to have different IDs, but then you've hardcoded a loop over two values into the class, that doesn't really make sense. Also things seem to be in the class that shouldn't be and what you've posted _doesn't_ give that error.

Comment: "it works on Mac not Windows": Are they using the same version of Python?

Comment: Is the `main()` function really inside the class?

Comment: You shouldn't use  an f-string and also `.format()`.

Comment: There're so many weird things in code, but still not clear what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Looking through it I think probably you just want`self.x = {str(id): []}`, I don't know what benefit you'd get from trying to misuse a property like that.

Answer (score 1):

You are using both `f""` and `str.format`, so you do formatting twice.
`str.format` interprets `1 {'1':[]}` as template string and tries to expand `'1'`, thus a `KeyError`.

**Edit**:
Removing either of them solves the problem. As to why it behaves differently: `'1'` is not a valid identifier. So the template string is ill-formed and the behavior is not specified (at least not in the documentation).

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are right that I am using formatting twice. Just do not understand why it works on Mac but not Windows. There was a question of whether my Python version takes account of that is I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks great responses and recommendations. Yes, I am sure many of you see 'weird' stuff in my codes because I do not fully explained the purposes. Yes, I should not use defaultdict instead of a simple dict. Yes, I was using f'' also .format(). Thanks for the lesson.

What works across platform is could be simple but want your feedback.
'''

class A:

```
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x   # id
        self.y = {}  # key = days, value = activities 
    
    def make_day(self):
    ''' each inst accepts random days and days have random activities'''
        random_days =  ['sorted','string','days','sampled','from','week']
        for each_day in random_days:
            self.y[each_day] = []
        return self.y
    
     def __str__(self):
        return f'%d, %s'%(self.x, self.y)
```

def main():
for i in range(2):
a = A(i)
a.make_day()
print(a)
if **name** == '**main**':
main()

0, {'sorted': [], ..., 'week': []}
1, {'sorted': [], ..., 'week': []}

'''

Comment: Please, can you edit your answer and format correctly the code? is just to improve the quality and legibility of your answer.

Comment: The user needs to edit the answer and improve the code format.